# mail:inbound-channel-adapter return type

Tags: spring-integration

I am setting up a *mail:inbound-channel-adapter* using Java annotations and `ImapIdleChannelAdapter`.

It is not clear what object type to pass from `@InboundChannelAdapter` to `@ServiceActivator`.

Code snippet:

```
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "inputChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
public ImapIdleChannelAdapter getMailAdapter() {
    ImapMailReceiver mailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver("imaps://username:password@map-mail.outlook.com:993/INBOX");
    ...
    return new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(mailReceiver);
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputChannel")
public void readMessage(Message<javax.mail.Message> message) {
    System.out.println(message.getPayload().getAllRecipients());
}
```

`ImapIdleChannelAdapter` source says that "The Message payload will be the javax.mail.Message instance that was received". Nevertheless, I receive a class cast exception `ImapIdleChannelAdapter cannot be cast to javax.mail.Message` when running the code above.

If I change SA's method argument to javax.mail.Message, I am getting `spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call cannot be found on .. type`

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputChannel")
public void readMessage(javax.mail.Message message) throws MessagingException {
    System.out.println(message.getAllRecipients());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` is an event-driven component. It’s not a source to poll. It will produce messages by its own internal tasks.

You must remove an `@InboundChannelAdapter` from its configuration and add simple `@Bean`. The `channel` must be configured one `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` object directly.